# How to change the message date of an email in Salesforce

Tags: email, email2case

I have just attached a bunch (non-scientific term!) of emails to a case by using the case ref in the email subject header. However, they are all saved with the same date even though i received them in my inbox on different dates. Is there a way fro me to change the message date of each email so that it reflects the date it was orignially sent on? I don't mind manually updating the date.

Comment: How did you attach them?

Comment: I didn't... I sent the email to case by putting the case ref in the subject and using the "email to case" tool in outlook, that way the attachment are automatically joined to the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case emails are SObject `EmailMessage`.

Per the doc, the field `MessageDate` can be Updated - but you won't be able to do this with the UI - you'll need to use SFDC Workbench, Data Loader, or anonymous Apex

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Salesforce for Outlook plugin](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewQuickStarts?id=000113374&language=en_US), it will create the email in Salesforce with the date and time you received or sent the email. It sounds like you forwarded the email to the email to case address.